# About peewee transaction commit

Tags: python, peewee

I am using mysql 8.0, using the innodb engine, using the version of peewee 3.14, I use peewee transaction commit, without executing commit, I saw the data has been written into the database, but I did not execute `db.commit()` , I manually execute commands in MySQL. If I don’t execute commit, I won’t be able to write. However, there will be inconsistencies when using peewee transaction commit. What is wrong with my code?

```
db =db = MySQLDatabase("address", host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="xxx",autocommit=False,autorollback=True)
with db.manual_commit():
    db.begin()
    Spead.create(dis="test",number="test",value=333)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also opened an issue on the peewee issue tracker, where I've responded with the following comment:

> I saw the data has been written into the database

Assuming you mean you were using a separate connection and saw the data before it had been committed by the peewee connection? You might check your read [isolation settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

When I run the following script I get the expected output -- the 2nd connection does not see the uncommitted row until I call commit:

```py
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('peewee_test')
db2 = MySQLDatabase('peewee_test')  # 2nd connection

class Reg(Model):
    key = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Reg2(Reg):  # model class for accessing table using 2nd conn
    class Meta:
        database = db2
        table_name = 'reg'


db.create_tables([Reg])

with db.manual_commit() as tx:
    db.begin()
    Reg.create(key='k1')  # create a row using first conn

    db2.connect()  # query table using 2nd conn
    print('is "k1" visible to conn2 BEFORE commit?')
    print('rows in "reg" table: %s' % Reg2.select().count())

    db.commit()
    print('is "k1" visible to conn2 AFTER commit?')
    print('rows in "reg" table: %s' % Reg2.select().count())

    db2.close()

db.drop_tables([Reg])
```

Output:

```
is "k1" visible to conn2 BEFORE commit?                                                                              
rows in "reg" table: 0                                                                                               
is "k1" visible to conn2 AFTER commit?                                                                               
rows in "reg" table: 1
```